# What is this red Texture?

Tags: texturing, transparency

So I ripped some Models from COD MW Remastered and I want to use them in Blender.
There is this redish like transparent texture that I don't know what it's for.
The texture is referred as "rvl". I would appreciate some answers cause I can't figure out,
what it's supposed to be.

This is, what the texture looks like:

[image: Image name is "h1_price_head_rvl"]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the texture isn't meant to be used as is, but is instead a pack of three different textures in each channel.

If we look at the RGB channels individually, it looks like this:

[image: RGB split]

This technique is referred to as "Channel Packing" and is commonly used in video games to save memory usage.

One of the common combination is Roughness + Metallic + Ambient occlusion, though here I guess the first channel is for roughness (because of the R and how it looks), but the others don't look like metallic or AO, so I'm not sure. It could be something completely different.

Maybe you can find a modding website for that game where people already figured this out.

To learn more:

[Channel Packing - polycount](http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/ChannelPacking)